# Emacs on Putty suddenly stopped accepting ctrl-space?

Tags: emacs, keyboard, putty

Weirdly, ctrl-space to start a mark works on the command line in putty and on X on the machine, just not in putty. What configuration did I break?

Answer (score 0):

That other question doesn't apply, because the ctrl-space is sent to the command line in putty, just not to emacs.